# Is the number of distinct characters of a finite group finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $V$ a finite complex vector space and $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ be a representation of $G$ in $V$. The character $\chi_{\rho}$ associated to $\rho$ is a mapping $\chi_{\rho}: G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ defined by:
$$\chi_{\rho}(g) := \text{Tr}(\rho(g))$$
It is an important result of the theory of representations of finite groups that two isomorphic representations give the same character.

**Question:** Is the number of *distinct* irreducible characters of a finite group $G$ finite?

Comment: Consider for any $n \in \mathbb N$ the representation $\rho_n : G \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb C^n)$ such that $\rho_n(g) = I_n$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: you have it slightly backwards; the important result is that two *non*-isomorphic representations give rise to *different* characters. (the other direction, that isomorphic representations give rise to the same character, is much more straightforward.) also, are you asking specifically about linear characters, ie $1$-dimensional representations? note that, if $\dim V>1$, the map $\chi_\rho:G\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ will in general definitely *not* be a group homomorphism. (this is not just a pedantic question, and it will affect the answer to your question)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom  I'm considering $\text{dim}V$ to be finite, but not necessarily equals to one. I edited it! Thanks!

Comment: The whole number multiples of the trivial character are all distinct characters. The virtual characters, as an abelian group, are free abelian spanned by irreducible characters. Perhaps you're asking about irreducible characters? Every irreducible representation is a summand of the regular representation, which implies there are finitely many of them (up to isomorphism).

Comment: @IamWill okay, do you see why $\chi_\rho$ will in general not be a group homomorphism if $\dim V>1$? (also, as a follow-up question: are you asking about *arbitrary* characters, or specifically *irreducible* characters? in the first case, then there are infinitely many such, as Rushy and runway44 have pointed out. but in the latter case, it is a consequence of [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) that there are only finitely many such.)

Comment: So, if I understand the comments correctly, the number of distinct characters is not finite? But what about the fact that result that $\chi_{1},...,\chi_{k}$ forms a basis for the space of class functions? Aren't we assuming there is a finite number of distinct characters?

Comment: @IamWill that theorem refers specifically to *irreducible* characters. do you know the definition of an irreducible representation?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom yes! Correct! I forgot to mention they are irreducible!!

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I know the result which states that every representation is the direct sum of irreducible representations, but I don't know how to use it to prove that there exists only a finite number of  distinct irreducible characters. Is it too easy and I'm missing something? Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: okay, if you know that every $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $G$ is a direct sum of irreducibles, then you are halfway there! :) to finish the proof it's easiest to think in terms of the "group algebra" $\mathbb{C}G$. are you familiar with this construction?

Comment: @atticusStonestrom I've just heard about. But I don't even remember the definition of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple different ways to prove this.  By the [Schur orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations), distinct irreducible characters are orthogonal to each other with respect to the dot product on $\mathbb{C}^G$.  (This is because up to normalizing by a factor of $|G|$, the dot product of two characters counts the dimension of the space of homomorphisms between the corresponding representations, which is $0$ for distinct irreducible representations by Schur's lemma.)  In particular, they are linearly independent, so there can be at most $|G|$ of them.  (More strongly, they sit inside the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^G$ consisting of functions that are constant on each conjugacy class, so the number of irreducible characters is at most the number of conjugacy classes; it turns out it is actually equal to the number of conjugacy classes.)

Alternatively, the regular representation can be decomposed as a finite direct sum of irreducible representations $\rho_i$.  But every irreducible representation has a nontrivial homomorphism from the regular representation (since the regular representation is the free $\mathbb{C}G$-module on one generator), and then this homomorphism must be nontrivial when restricted to one of the summands $\rho_i$.  By Schur's lemma, this means that each irreducible representation must be isomorphic to one of the $\rho_i$.

Comment: Eric, thank your for your answer. Your first argument seems more close to what I'm looking for. However, I'm still missing the link. Why linear independence implies there are at most $|G|$ of them?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^G$ is a $|G|$-dimensional vector space.